# I want to store and retrieve html data in mvc by setting validate(false)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor, model-view-controller

If I use `@html.Raw()` Html is executing very well.. but some people saying that displaying data(html) using `@html.Raw()` will lead to XSS attacks.

But alternatively we don't have any choice to display html data in mvc...
Is there any way to achieve this?

```
<h1 class="art-heading">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Article_Name)</h1>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Article_Content)
</div>
<section>
    @Html.Raw(Model.code)
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use: MvcHtmlString look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) for more information about this class

```
public MvcHtmlString OutputHtml() {
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<div>My div</div>");
}
```

then in view:

```
@OutputHtml()
```